# Overlapping text when saving multiple Matplotlib images with text in a loop

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, text, colormap

I created this randomly-valued/coloured 'chessboard':

[image: chessboard]

with the code:

```
rndm = np.random.rand(8,8)
my_cmap = plt.get_cmap('gray') 

plt.figure(figsize=(5,4))
plt.imshow(rndm, cmap=my_cmap, interpolation = 'none')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

I wanted to apply a function to the values in a loop, for example raising all values in the array to an increasing power, and then show all in different subplots. Here's the code:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(10, 10))
axs = axs.ravel()

for i, n in zip(np.arange(4), np.arange(2,6)):
    axs[i].imshow(np.power(rndm, n), cmap=my_cmap, interpolation = 'none')
    axs[i].axis('off')
    axs[i].text(1, 1, str(n), fontsize=14, color = 'y')
```

and the result:

[image: subplots]

But what I would really like is to cycle through 4 colormaps, for example:

```
cmaps = ['viridis', 'inferno', 'plasma', 'magma']
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(10, 10))
axs = axs.ravel()

for i, n in zip(np.arange(4), np.arange(2,6)):
    axs[i].imshow(np.power(rndm, n), cmap=cmaps[i], interpolation = 'none')
    axs[i].axis('off')
    axs[i].text(1, 1, str(n), fontsize=14, color = 'y')
```

[image: coloured subplots]

Good. But here's where my code breaks. I want to save these as individual images.
I wrote this, which is fine except for the fact that the text numbers end up superimposed:

```
for i, n in zip(np.arange(4), np.arange(2,6)):
    plt.imshow(np.power(rndm, n), cmap=cmaps[i], interpolation = 'none')
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.text(1, 1, str(n), fontsize=14, color = 'y')
    plt.savefig("test_n = " + str(n) +".png", dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

[image]

How do I clear them each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you use `cmaps[i]` instead of `cmap=my_cmap`? 
Create a figure in each loop using `plt.figure()` and it'll work correctly (tested).

```
for i, n in zip(np.arange(4), np.arange(2,6)):
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(np.power(rndm, n), cmap=cmaps[i], interpolation = 'none')
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.text(1, 1, str(n), fontsize=14, color = 'y')
    plt.savefig("test_n = " + str(n) +".png", dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

result:

- The main image (not saved) : 
  [image]

-Saved images:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Note that the labels starts from 2 because of this line :

```
plt.text(1, 1, str(n), fontsize=14, color = 'y')
```

If you want it start from 1 , change `str(n)` to `str(i)`.

Comment: Sorry, the cmap=my_cmap was just a typo. In my original code I had it right. But the plt.figure() will fix it. Thank you for your answer. I like the str(n) because that's the exponent.

Comment: I now edited the question to remove the cmap=my_cmap error, so it is not confusing to future readers. Thanks again @Yugi